# CoreData save doesn’t work inside Model, but works inside View

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am trying to use a `Model` to call a `function` within a `Child View` that should save to a `Core Data` object. The model works correctly until it reaches `viewContext.save()` when it prints the error string. The view updates as it should, but the values are not save to the CoreData. I was previously doing this in the view, which worked.

```
class NewShotModel: ObservableObject {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel
    func addNewShot(shotClub: Club, newShot: Int, waiting: Bool, club: Club) -> Void {
        let club = shotClub
        let newShot = newShot
        club.strokesList.append(newShot)
        club.strokes = club.strokesList.count
        let sumArray = club.strokesList.reduce(0,+)
        club.yardsNum = sumArray / club.strokes
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
            print("shot saved")
            locationManager.shotCoord = locationManager.ballCoord
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ClubDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var club: Club
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel
    @State var newShot: Int = 0
    @Binding var waiting: Bool
    @Binding var shotCoord: CLLocation?
    @Binding var ballCoord: CLLocation?
    @Binding var shotClub: Club
    @Binding var distanceYards: Int? 
    @ObservedObject var addNewShot = NewShotModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        List {
            if self.club.putter == false {
                Section {
                    Text(self.club.name)
                    Text("Average distance: \(club.yardsNum) yards")
                    Text("\(club.strokes) Strokes Counted")
                }
            } else {Text("This app is not designed to track putting data at this time.")}
        }
        if waiting == false && club.putter == false {
            Button(action: {locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .shot)
                waiting = true
                shotClub = club
            },label: {
                Text("Swing Location")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
            
        if waiting == true && club.putter == false{
            Button(action: {locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .ball)
            }, label: {
                Text("Ball Location")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        if waiting == true && club.putter == true{
            Button(action: {
                shotClub = club
                if shotClub.putter == true {
                    waiting = false
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Start Putting")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Timmy I was handling the error by printing “error”, but when I change error handling to

 `do {
            try viewContext.save()
            print("shot saved")
            locationManager.shotCoord = locationManager.ballCoord
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError.localizedDescription)")
        }`
 it returns “ Unresolved error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)”

Comment: It is not recommended that you use `@Environment` in something other than a `View`. Use the injected `NSManagedObjectContext` directly or pass it as a parameter instead.